# GetBindingExpression is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

Tags: vb.net, csla

I'm trying to use the .UpdateSource of a textbox(bound to a datasource) in vb.net with csla framework.

The code I have :

```
    Dim t As TextBox = TryCast(txtTest1, TextBox)
    Dim BindingExpr As BindingExpression = t.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.Text)
    bindingExpr.UpdateSource()
```

I have added the reference PresentaionFramework and put in the

```
    Imports System.Windows.Data
```

I am getting this error :

```
    "GetBindingExpression is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.TextBox"
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK [GetBindingExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.getbindingexpression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is specific to WPF and will not work in WinForms.